# How to scroll info windows in map v2?

Tags: android, dictionary, infowindow

i make a one app like a see data on a info windows my data is very long and i used scroll view for scroll info windows but not getting scroll event in map v2 so, tell me is it possible to scroll data on info windows in map.

i tried google but not getting any out put so i put my query here.

please see my below images. my data cut at bottom of the info windows but when i scroll info windows get map scroll event..

[image: Error on this image]

**This is my layout file..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_not_available"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_zp" >
</ImageView>

 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_company"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/lbl_company"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/snippet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_company"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/snippet"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/lbl_desc"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_description"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/snippet"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_salary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/lbl_salary"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/salary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_salary"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/snippet"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_instructions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/lbl_instructions"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/instructions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_instructions"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/snippet"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @GrIsHu add layout please check..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think ScrollView is possible inside Custom `InfoWindow`. You can achieve your goal by following way.

`Onclick` of `InfoWindow` display dialog with entire description.

Like...

```
 map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(GoogleMAPV2Activity.this,
                    Customdialog.class));
            //here pass your data in intent

        }
    });
```

`Customdialog` contains `TextView` which displays your entire data.

Here are the screenshots :

[image]

[image]

This is alternative way of your requirement, but you can also use this. Hope it helps.
Thanks,
Happy Codding.